# Graph multicolor area line

Tags: charts, highcharts, area

i need to create graph as [showed on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGAO6.png).

One line with color filled area,
if point value is more than zero than color of line and area is green, else red.

How can i do this? JS (some plugin?) or PHP (imagick, gd)

Comment: Disclamer: I'm image-charts founder ( https://image-charts.com) . If you need to generate an image of a line graph, it's simple as a URL: https://image-charts.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=700x125&chd=s:ATSTaVd21981uocA&chco=224499&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|1:||50|100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) area series type and define `negativeColor` for it. Check the docs and example posted below.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'area'
  },
  series: [{
    color: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.7)',
    negativeColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)',
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    marker: {
        enabled: false
    },
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2, -3, -5, -2, -7, -4, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1]
  }]
});
```

Demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xa91d8o7/4/

Docs: 
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-negative 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area